# Are PhDs always obligated to stay involved in research, even after graduation?

Tags: publications, research-process, career-path, job-search, early-career

I have the impression that PhDs are expected to always be involved in research and have (or eventually get) some sort of peer reviewed publication, even after graduation.

I'm gravely concerned now about this PhD forever "branding" me into sticking to research output when this isn't the right choice for me.  I'm even going as far as considering dropping my Ph.D despite already proposing and nearly being finished with data collection. If I do not keep up with the additional expectations, what value does my PhD have? I'm likely going to cut my losses and go straight to working since it seems like a PhD means I'll always be expected to be involved in research in some capacity.

Comment: Do you know phd holders who are not in Academia? What is your impression about them? Where did you get the premise from?

Comment: "*I have the impression that PhDs are expected to always be involved in research and have (or eventually get) some sort of peer reviewed publication, even after graduation.*"  Honest question: What gave you that impression? (In my country, lots of people outside of academia have a PhD and, thus, carry a "Dr." in front of their name - politicians, public officials, managers, school teachers, lawyers, etc. I genuinely wonder why anyone would consider them to be active researchers.)

Comment: Who would be expecting it? And in what way would those people have any say in what you decide to do?

Comment: You write "obligated" in the title, but "expected" in the text. That latter word is much softer and more ambiguous here: people expect things that aren't true all the time. But "obligated" also requires someone to enforce the obligation. Who do you expect that to be? (i.e. are you considering if there's some law to limit the allowed occupations of people with a particular degree, or that the Doctor's Guild would send their henchmen to punish any doctors that desecrated their Order by taking on mundate jobs?)

Answer (score 28):

There are many careers open to people with doctorates and, as people, other careers that they might pursue that don't require doctorates. Some people will "brand" you as a researcher if you have a PhD, but that is incorrect. You are free to choose any career for which you are interested and can develop the qualifications. Some technical PhDs actually go in to management rather than academia.

Another common career path for a PhD is in small teaching colleges that put much less emphasis on research and much more on good teaching at the undergraduate level. There is some expectation of research but it is usually of a different sort than was done for the doctorate. For example a math PhD might do their research in math education (pedagogy) rather than in math. Such a career can be very rewarding and much less stressful.

But the important thing to remember is that you only have one life and you want to find a way to live it that is satisfying to yourself and others who might depend on you. If you find research at a high level to be overly stressful, there are other options, but you have to find them, and you have to work to develop the skills they require. Alternatively, find a way to reduce the stress, though that may require professional help.

Comment: I once hired a PhD as a technologist. They liked the hands on lab work and didn’t like chasing funding. Worked out well for everyone.

Comment: Other comments will elaborate but I'm currently applying to a bunch of job matching and internship services right now that should help me find a job.

Answer (score 20):

I am a math Ph.D. and working in industry. I personally do publish once in a while, not so much because my position requires me to do so, but more because I like it. However, I have multiple colleagues with Ph.D.s in software engineering and related fields, and they do not publish at all. This is absolutely fine.

In addition, I have some visibility into what happens to my wife's Ph.D. students in psychology. The vast majority of them go into clinical practice as psychotherapists, some into other areas in industry. Again, almost none of them publish ever again.

Yes, there are research positions in industry, and some of them expect or require you to publish. But there are also many, many others, where the Ph.D. is mainly a [signaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signalling_(economics)) device, showing that you are self-motivated and smart enough to get a Ph.D. You are essentially competing with other candidates without a Ph.D. but possibly with a few years of work experience. Your task is to explain to the hiring manager that the Ph.D. may not have given you specific industry experience, but that it shows you can dig into the specific field you are applying to.

Naturally, most questions on Academia.SE about academia-industry transitions lean towards "research side" emphasis. People who chose the "go into industry and never publish again" path are less likely to post here, because they simply tick differently. The picture you get here is likely somewhat distorted because of this [selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias).

> I'm even going as far as considering dropping my Ph.D despite already proposing and nearly being finished with data collection.

Be very careful about this. You sound as if you thought that a Ph.D. would be a hindrance on your CV. It won't. Even if you [graduate without publications](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/205084/4140), that is still better than quitting 80% through. Finishing the Ph.D. shows that you persist in face of difficulties. That is a valuable skill.

(Note that I am saying to be careful, not to persist no matter what. Depending on your circumstances, cutting your losses may indeed be smart, and knowing when to quit can be quite as valuable as persisting. You need to weigh the additional effort required to get that [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheepskin_effect) against the alternatives. Just don't think that a Ph.D. will be a hindrance - compared to the alternatives, it most likely won't.)

Comment: "be a hindrance"..."it won't". It might, though (depending on location).

Comment: I appreciate this answer since it's definitely more nuanced in this case. I consistently feel like I picked the wrong field sometimes since Experimental Psychology specifically is one that's research based and I didn't realize I never had the capacity to be a full blown researcher (despite the skills I've developed through this program) until recently. Folks have to sell themselves to employers as well and that's not something I've ever been good at doing at all nor have I developed that skill independently (there's someone who I consult bi-weekly that helps me with that though).

Comment: An outside voice can be extremely helpful, especially for those of us that spend most of their time in an academic environment. Your university may also offer other kinds of support, since it has a vested interest in their graduates finding suitable work.

Comment: @user111388 citation needed.

Comment: @fectin: Why don't you also ask for citations for the more general statement that it wouldn't be a hindrance?;) anyway, anecdotal evidence: in my company (and in others in my country), phds are - at the beginning of their industry emploment - to be better paid than people with only a master's, even if they have no industry-relevant skills. This makes them slighly worse than masters. (which does obviously not mean  they can never land a job, I am also a phd and got hired:))

Comment: "because they simply tick differently" - or because they are subject to very different external factors.

Comment: @zzmondo1 "[...] since Experimental Psychology specifically is one that's research based". This may blows your mind, but sciences in general are **all** research based. Doing a PhD is learning how to be a researcher. Academia is research, PhDs do research. All is research, in all fields. Which fields would you consider "less research based"? Not to go for a discussion here, but there is probably some misunderstanding around.

Answer (score 12):

Certainly not. There's nothing stopping you from retiring and becoming a homemaker even if you have a PhD, as long as you have the $$$ to support yourself. Less extremely, there are plenty of jobs that ask for a PhD, but do not involve research. [Example](https://www.recruit.net/job/business-development-specialist-jobs/1AA8EDDEB31B1E1E).

It sounds like you're unfamiliar with the job market (the assumption that you can "go straight to working" is a red flag). You should definitely get familiar with your local job market before making decisions like whether you should quit your PhD. Go to your local jobs portal and find what jobs are available that you can already do, and preferably apply + get some interview practice, before making such a decision.

Comment: I'm currently looking into job matching programs for those with disabilities like myself. I just got approved for vocational rehabilitation in addition to the Federal Workforce Recruitment Program so I'm going to see what I can get matched with that'll fit what I'm capable of doing at the moment. As for job markets, it looks like everything I can do is kind of scattered all over the country (US).

Comment: It has never occurred to me, nor have I previously heard any academic colleague express the idea, that a person who pursues a PhD should remain involved in research. Indeed, most of the PhD graduates that I know personally, are not involved in research!

Comment: There are also plenty of jobs that *don't* ask for a Ph.D., but for which someone with a Ph.D. might nevertheless be well qualified.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is no. The longer answer is you need to decide what you want to do. In your previous question you said you would graduate in May of 2024. That means you have done the lion's share of the work required to finish by now. If that is so, put the energy you are putting into worrying, complaining and posting on this site into finishing. A LOT of your concerns will dissolve when you have completed your dissertation, gotten your committee to sign off and are 100% ready to graduate. I know students like you that have gotten 90-95% of the way and quit. That is stupid bcuz it makes all of the challenges you worked through pointless! A PhD will help you significantly more than it will hurt you. Like publishing your work, it is up to you to push through and get it done. You can question. You can doubt. You can't quit!

Comment: Going to finally follow up with everyone from the bottom up (yours happened to be at the bottom). I'm going to be honest and say that as far as what I want to do goes, it's a bit out of my hands since I'm in vocational rehabilitation, the federal workforce recruitment program, and applying to two more programs that will match me with jobs (and even internships) which will accommodate me accordingly.

Comment: Your questions were not about any of that. Unless your other questions and comments are lies you do have some agency but you are panicking about all of these other things. The truth is your PI, your PhD committee, your PhD program and your institution have a vested interest in you graduating successfully. You need to concentrate on what is within your power to make that happen and do it, if you want to obtain a PhD. If not, quit. Its no more complicated than that.

Comment: @jason_white I see. Maybe a part of me is still thinking back to when my first PhD advisor dumped me before she was slated to leave my program anyway. My current advisor took me so he could graduate me but I am worried with the budget cuts and whatnot how much my institution is really vested in me graduating successfully at all.

Comment: @zzmondo1 Frankly, I think you are beyond help. A part of you seems to be looking for a way forward but you insist on dwelling on past, present or future challenges. The reason few ppl have terminal degrees is bcuz it is hard. That is not to discount individual challenges but it is to say you have to fight through them. Your previous comments suggest you are close to completion so I would say you have fought to get this far and should not give up BUT If you think the challenges are insurmountable just move on to something else that will you and us time.

Comment: @jason_white I've had a lot of folks insist on me dwelling but you're the first to explicitly yell me that I'm beyond help. That definitely hits hard. I should have also clarified but my last comment was meant for me to postulate as to why I'm doing what I'm doing now. I'm not going to quit and take into account concentrating on what I can do to achieve things.

Comment: @zzmondo1 Never listen to ppl that tell you to dwell on things you can't control. Doing that is destructive and a waste of time. That is a sure fire way of undermining anything that you are trying to accomplish. I am happy that those voices have not inspired you to quit. I wish you the best bcuz I know it is hard. The moment your committee signs off on your dissertation I guarantee you will feel so much better about your future.

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely not. I quit my postdoc and academia for good 12 years ago. Never published anything since, never attended any conference, never got involved in any kind of research, not even at my current company. Made a lot more money than I could have in academia even if I became a tenured full prof, and have enjoyed my work a lot more than I did in academia.

Stephan Kolassa's and other answers are very good. My point of writing this is so that you know there are many like myself who have quit research and academia and never looked back. By all means, finish your Ph.D. if you are close. The value of your Ph.D. is simply that you can say: "Look, I can solve a difficult problem if I want to." The best way to sell yourself to an employer or a customer is to know the field of business inside out and know where *you* can add value. Then pick highlights of your past experience as proof of credential.

For the sake of completeness, I spent 7 years in academia: 4 for MS + Ph.D. at a top ten (whatever that means) U.S. engineering program, and a little less than 3 as a postdoc also in engineering. The Ph.D. + publications gave me immigration benefits and a good starting pay. I reviewed articles for a journal here and there only to help my friend, who is an associate editor, when he finds it hard to find another reviewer for a paper.

Basically, work on whatever the heck you want and for whoever the heck you want, as long as you can sustain yourself (food, housing, security, family obligations, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Nope.

I'm in industry now and doing a part-time PhD in nothing related to my profession.

I have no plans on going into academia afterwards.

You have no obligations to anyone by virtue of having your PhD.

Answer (score 2):

Publish or perish applies only to academic position which require promotion after hired as assistant professor. Then you have to do research to be promoted to associate professor then to full professor. In such cases, universities put time limit on promotion, and if that is not met they let you go. So you may follow other advices given by others for other jobs.

Answer (score 0):

> I have the impression that PhDs are expected to always be involved in research and have (or eventually get) some sort of peer reviewed publication, even after graduation.

Only if you want to. I am a mere BSc, but I work in a team that develops mathematical modelling software, where something like half the staff have doctorates. We are "commercial R&D" if it needs a label, and will *occasionally* do a presentation at a conference, but our usual output is software and patents.

Answer (score -1):

> I have the impression that PhDs are expected to always be involved in research and have (or eventually get) some sort of peer reviewed publication, even after graduation.

If you mean **outside of Academia** then it is statistically unlikely that your PhD means much, not to mention following up on it.

I am now trying to recall one of the PhDs I met or worked with in the 30+ years I have worked in high tech across the world. And I cannot think of any, out of the maybe 20-50 I can think of. Myself included.

This of course does not account for the very few who were expected and wanted to do actual research.

Out of sheer curiosity, I had a look at our current government - there are 4 PhDs and the last thing they are doing is research.